# primefaces selectOneMenu doesn't working when it should

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm losing days with this strange problem, I double checked everything but my selectOneMenu simply doesn't works and I can't understand why.

So here are my codes:

My jsf

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="entityType"  
      value="#{entityBean.entity.type}" 
      style="width:240px;" 
      converter="entityTypeConverter"
      valueChangeListener="#{entityBean.entityTypeListener}"
      required="true">
      <f:selectItems value="#{entityBean.typeList}"
              var="et"
              itemLabel="#{et.name}"
              itemValue="#{et}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

My converter:

```
    @FacesConverter("entityTypeConverter")
    public class EntityTypeConverter implements Converter {
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            Long id = Long.parseLong(value);

            return EntityType.findEntityType(id);
        }

        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

            return value instanceof EntityType ? ((EntityType) value).getId().toString() : "";
        }
    }
```

It works as expected when I'm creating (it passes the selected value), but when I try to edit the entity the selected type actually never gets selected. I tried with primefaces 3.1.1 and 3.2 but I can't get the selected value when in view/edit mode.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The entity and entityType are just fantasy names

Comment: use `p:ajax` instead of the valueChangeListener...

Comment: Same problem without valueChangeListener. My problem is get the value selected when I load the edit page. I think the value="#{entityBean.entity.type}"  and the converter should do this, but apparently this doesn't works with me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That can happen if the `equals()` method of your `EntityType` class is missing or broken. Given the fact that you've an `id` property in your `EntityType` class which seems to identify the instance uniquely enough, the following minimal implementation should do it for you:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other instanceof EntityType) && (id != null)
        ? id.equals(((EntityType) other).id)
        : (other == this);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null)
        ? (this.getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode())
        : super.hashCode();
}
```

`hashCode()` is just mandatory as per `equals()` [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my equals method was missig! Now it's working fine!