# JSF / Primefaces 3.4.1 / SelectOneMenu / Pojo / Pre select pojo value not work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

This preselected autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer1 does not work !!

This is the example extracted from the showcase of primefaces site: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer1}" converter="player"> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{autoCompleteBean.players}" var="player" 
                   itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

In the bean, I put this lines :

```
private Player selectedPlayer1;
private List players;

/* AutoCompleteBean - constructor */ 

public AutoCompleteBean() {

players = new ArrayList<Player>();

players.add(new Player("Messi", 10, "messi.jpg", "CF"));
players.add(new Player("Bojan", 9, "bojan.jpg", "CF"));

selectedPlayer1 = players.get(1);
}
```

Variable autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer1, 
contain the value that you specify before opening the jsp.
But, this is not preselected. Only appear always selected the first element
of the arraylist. Why ??

Only I need that p:selectOneMenu, preselect de value in the list.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you put exact JSF code you wrote? Only then we can really help.

Comment: Hi jedrus07, I've made my question more explicit. Please read it and I hope your feedback. Thanks !!

Comment: Is the converter working well? No errors in logs?

Comment: Yes, the converter it's ok. I debuging and not errors found.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact you can pre-select a value, or in other words, select a value by default by doing this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer1}" effect="fade" converter="player">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer1.name" itemValue="autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer1" />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{autoCompleteBean.players}" var="player" itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player}"/>  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The only problem with this is that it will repeat the value selected-by-default like this:

[image]

And you I guess you would like something like this:

[image]

So for this matter, i will recommend you to use the array player:

```
itemValue="#{player}"
```

but removing from this array the pre-selected option

Comment: Thanks pmking !! I do it, but the problem now is the validator. When you submit this page, message error appear. I think that the converter not found the object in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Does your player class have hashCode() and equals() functions?

If they are missing, primefaces cannot make differences between them.

Similar problem:
[primefaces selectOneMenu doesn't working when it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726716/primefaces-selectonemenu-doesnt-working-when-it-should)