# SelectOneMenu always shows first item not the selected - Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, selectedvalue

Some help would be appreciated on this issue.

I have several JSF Pages, but one of them is a Subcategory where there is a **SelectOneMenu** for choosing the **Category**, but when I try to edit the subcategory, this **SelectOneMenu** always shows the first value and is not getting preselected.

How could I solve this. I have read a lot of **SO posts** and eventhougn I have implemented a couple of advice I have not achieved it. for example, a **@BalusC**'s one:

[primefaces selectOneMenu doesn't working when it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726716/primefaces-selectonemenu-doesnt-working-when-it-should)

**Here is the View**

```
<h:outputText value="Subcategory ID : #{subcategoryController.subcategory.subcategoryId}"/>

<p:selectOneMenu id="cboCategoryDialog" converter="subcategoryConverter"
                 value="#{subcategoryController.category.categoryId}"
                 style="width: 100%"

    <f:selectItems value="#{subcategoryController.categoryList}"
                   var="subcat"
                   itemLabel="#{subcat.categoryName}"
                   itemValue="#{subcat.categoryId}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>**
```

**This is the Subcategory Entity:**

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "subcategory_id")
private Integer subcategoryId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "subcategory_name")
private String subcategoryName;
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id")
@OneToOne(optional = false;
private Category categoryId;

//Getters and Setters Methods

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (subcategoryId != null)
            ? (this.getClass().hashCode() + subcategoryId.hashCode())
            : super.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    return (obj instanceof Subcategory) && (subcategoryId != null)
            ? subcategoryId.equals(((Subcategory) obj).subcategoryId)
            : (obj == this);
}
```

**SubcategoryConverter**

```
@RequestScoped
@FacesConverter("subcategoryConverter")
public class SubcategoryConverter implements Converter {

@EJB
private SubcategoryFacadeLocal EJBsubcategory;

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (!(value instanceof Subcategory) || ((Subcategory) value).getSubcategoryId() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return String.valueOf(((Subcategory) value).getSubcategoryId());
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null || !value.matches("\\d+")) {
        return null;
    }

    Subcategory subcategory = EJBsubcategory.find(Integer.valueOf(value));

    if (subcategory == null) {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Unknown operation ID: " + value));
    }

    return subcategory;

    }
}
```

Below image shows the Dialog when I try to edit any item, it always shows computer because its the first itm.

[See the image showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgUeI.jpg)

I have been reading some related useful questions about this, but I have not been able to fix it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: where is your converter ?
what's subcategoryController.category.categoryId ?

Comment: I'm using Onmifaces SelectItemsConverter. subcategoryController.category.categoryId is where the selected category is saved in subcategory entity. @Arun

Comment: pls post converter code

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I added the converter. @Arun

Comment: I think the whole problem is "subcategoryController.categoryList". This is not the list you should be using. You need a list with categoryId objects and not subcat objects. Try to change something like this....

<f:selectItems value="#{subcategoryController.categoryList}"
                   var="cat"
                   itemLabel="#{cat.categoryName}"
                   itemValue="#{#cat}"/>
because in selectOneMenu, its cat obj, so selecteItems must also have cat object rather than subcat object

Comment: No yet, unfortunately. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'll keep investigating and, once done, I will post it here. Thanks, Man. @Arun

Comment: Problem solved. I was using the wrong entity in the selectOneMenu. I use: subcategoryController.category.categoryId, and the correct one, since I was working with subcategory entities is: subcategoryController.subcategory.categoryId

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the code, I realized that I was using the wrong entity in the **JSF.**:

**For example:**

In the question, I posted: subcategoryController.category.categoryId to save **Category** object in a **subcategory** object.

As follow:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="cboCategoryDialog" converter="subcategoryConverter"
    value="#{subcategoryController.category.categoryId}"
```

But, the correct approach is the following:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="cboCategoryDialog" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
    value="#{subcategoryController.subcategory.categoryId}"
```

Now, this component is "pointing" to the correct object.

Another issue that I was facing is:

As I have nested entities, example: **Entity.entity.entity** they should be inicialized in every level, before using it.

Some posts that really, really, really helped me on this:

On solving the nested entities issues **(PropertyNotFoundException)**.

[Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)

On using normal and OmniFaces Converter on SelectOneMenu:

http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your entity hashCode() and equals() methods are implemented and doesn't try to access nullable fields. That worked for me!